# how to parse XML file which i add to my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

i have made a custom NSObject class which i use to parse an XML page, there it is:

```
#import "requestManager.h"


@implementation requestManager

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<requestDelegate>)delegateObj{

    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.delegate = delegateObj;
        self.contentData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.listOfPlaces = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)loadXmlData{


    NSURL *urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [conn start];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [self.contentData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSXMLParser *parserObj  =[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.contentData];
    parserObj.delegate = self;
    [parserObj parse];

    NSLog(@"FINISHLOADING");
    [self.delegate didFinishParsingToDatabase:self.listOfPlaces];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"error!");
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


    if (isName) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"name"];
    if (isDescription) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"description"];
    if (isLatitude) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"latitude"];
    if (isLongitude) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"longitude"];;
    if (isWebPage) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"webPage"];
    if (isImageCell) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"imageCell"];
    if (isImageFirst) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"imageFirst"];
    if (isImageSecond) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"imageSecond"];
    if (isImageThird) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"imageThird"];
    if (isImageFourth) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"imageFourth"];


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"place"]){
        self.currentPosition = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) isName = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) isDescription = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"]) isLatitude = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) isLongitude = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageCell"]) isImageCell = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageSecond"]) isImageSecond = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageThird"]) isImageThird = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageFourth"]) isImageFourth = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"webpage"]) isWebPage = YES;

}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{



    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) isName = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) isDescription = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"]) isLatitude = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) isLongitude = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageCell"]) isImageCell = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageSecond"]) isImageSecond = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageThird"]) isImageThird = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"imageFourth"]) isImageFourth = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"webpage"]) isWebPage = NO;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"place"]){
        //    self.currentPosition = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//        NSLog(@"%@", self.currentPosition);
        [self.listOfPlaces addObject:self.currentPosition];
              NSLog(@"%@", self.listOfPlaces);
    }

}


//-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
//    
//    
//}


@end
```

What i want is to add an xml file to my project and parse it Offline. How should i implement that? Should i write another class for it, or modify existing?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have the *download* of your XML file coupled with the *parsing* of your XML file. If you separate those two functions then you'll be able either download it *or* load it from your Bundle and then use the exact same code to parse it.

Look at your connectionDidFinishLoading method. Extract the methods there and put them in their own class and then call that class. Get it working first. (This is called refactoring.)

Next you can open an XML file from your Bundle, get the NSData from it, and then call the class you just made.